# spring boot - exclude bean from component scan does not work in XML

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I need to exclude these two packages based on any conditional value from an external source before running my application.

Since I need to determine these packages based on an external value before building , I cant use hardcoded annotations.

@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.ReadDB.reader",
excludeFilters = {
@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\.ReadDB\.reader\.opendental\..*"),
@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\.ReadDB\.reader\.mysql\..*")
}
)

this annotation on my main class is working ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ReadDB.reader">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.ReadDB\.reader\.opendental\..*"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.ReadDB\.reader\.mysql\..*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

but this xml file in my resources folder and @ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml") annotation on my main class is not working.

Any idea on how to fix this.

Comment: Hi Ruth. Would it be possible for you to provide your project? (or a stripped down demo of it). You can upload it to https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the id of the upload here.